# Pandas Method chaining and adding a new column

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I am trying to make a new column in Pandas called "Depreciation" like below:

```
(omc_e.query('GL_account == "740190" and Posting_date > "2021-06-30"')
    .groupby(['Business_segment_item'], as_index=False)
    ['Amount_DKK']
    .sum()
    .assign( Depreciation = lambda x: 0 if x.Business_segment_item == "" else x.Amount_DKK)
)
```

But I get an error when trying to run it:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I can of course make a new dataframe "test" and run the same method and then it works:

```
test[['Business_segment_item', 'Amount_DKK']].apply(lambda x: 0 if x.Business_segment_item == "" else x.Amount_DKK, axis = 1)
```

So it must be my method chaining that is causing the trouble, but can I avoid that and still use method chaining in order to avoid a lot of temporary dataframes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
(omc_e.query('GL_account == "740190" and Posting_date > "2021-06-30"')
    .groupby(['Business_segment_item'], as_index=False)
    ['Amount_DKK']
    .sum()
    .assign( Depreciation = lambda x: np.where(x.Business_segment_item == "" , 0, x.Amount_DKK))
)
```

Comment: That does indeed work - is there no way around using np.where? Just that it (to me) makes it a bit more difficult to read?

Comment: @Morten_DK - it is vectorized `if-else` for working with arrays - your `if-else` solution is for scalars.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, that may offer a *cleaner* abstraction, is to use the [case_when](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.case_when.case_when) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), which replicates the case when function from SQL:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
(omc_e.query('GL_account == "740190" and Posting_date > "2021-06-30"')
    .groupby(['Business_segment_item'], as_index=False)
    ['Amount_DKK']
    .sum()
    .case_when(lambda x: x.Business_segment_item == "", # condition
               0, # result if True
               lambda x: x.Amount_DKK, # result if False
               column_name = 'Depreciation')
)
```

You can have a look at more examples [here](https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor-examples/blob/main/docs/case_when.ipynb)